# Error al Guardar Formulario

Tags: python, django

url.py

```
     url(r'^paciente/(?P<pk>\d+)/', PatientDetails.as_view(), name='patient_details'),
```

view.py

```
def add_deworming(request, pk):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DewormingForm(request.POST, patient=Patient.objects.get(pk=pk))
    if form.is_valid():
        deworming = form.save()
        patient=Patient.objects.get(pk=pk)

        return redirect('clinic:patient_detail', patient.pk)
else:
    form = DewormingForm()
return render_to_response('clinic/medicalrecord/register_deworming.html', {'form_deworming': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

obtengo el siguiente error

> Reverse for 'patient_detail' with arguments '(3L,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

me señala esta linea

```
            return redirect('clinic:patient_detail', patient.pk)
```

que puedo tener mal?

Comment: Gracias por editar tu pregunta, tengo algunas sugerencias: ¿qué información estabas enviando?. Por favor lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** para conocer mas detalles y así mejorar aún mas tu pregunta. Revisa esta [respuesta _en inglés_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13202435/4092887) e intenta buscar `reverse for pattern with arguments django` o `reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []` en Google - si aún no lo has hecho. Saludos.

Comment: La URL que pones no corresponde a la que tiene el error, que es `patient_detail`, ¿podrías editar tu pregunta para agregar los datos faltantes?

Comment: Puedes añadir las urls de tu proyecto, la URL que colocas no corresponde a que llamas en el View, quizás el error pueda estar es que la que llamas no recibe un parámetro como el que pasas, pero no lo sabremos hasta que no coloques la info faltante

Comment: ya corregi el error, no era esa la url, ya puse en la pregunta la correcta espero les sea de ayuda @toledano

Comment: Si has encontrado la solución, por favor pública la respuesta y cierra la pregunta

Comment: no aun no solo puse en la pregunta la url correcta habia copiado la que no era

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás usando mal `redirect()`.

Como alternativa usa `HttpResponseRedirect` junto con `reverse()` de la siguiente manera:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('patient_details', pk=patient.pk))
```

Consulta la documentación de [`HttpResponseRedirect()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) y de [`reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse).